# Can a character show fur only on sharp edges?

Tags: particles

I want to do an effect where there is no fur shown on a character until there's a bend. I mean there is no fur at all visible just polygons other than strategic locations under certain conditions.

EG: An arm is straight there is no fur seen on the elbow unless the elbow is bent then you would see a spike of fur.

How do I do this in the least complicated yet effective way?

[image]